# Remove image from div and textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I just finished to clone images from div to another div and textarea, but I dont know how to remove cloned images, if I dont want that...

here is sample:

```js
function removeFunction() {
  var clonedimage = document.getElementById("2");
  clonedimage.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="clone-for-view">
<ul><span>2 images cloned:</span> 
<li> 
<img alt="" id="2" src="image1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail edit">
<span onclick='removeFunction()'>Remove image</span>
</li> 
<li>
<img alt="" id="3" src="image2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail edit">
<span onclick='removeFunction()'>Remove image</span>
</li> 
</ul>
</div>

<textarea id="clone-for-database">
<ul><span>2 images cloned:</span> 
<li> 
<img alt="" id="2" src="image1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail edit">
<span onclick='removeFunction()'>Remove image</span>
</li> 
<li>
<img alt="" id="3" src="image2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail edit">
<span onclick='removeFunction()'>Remove image</span>
</li> 
</ul>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Could you provide more details and add some clarity? The more you say, the more we can understand. Try read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: An ID must be unique in the document.

Comment: I want to remove  image by clicking on span button, and if I will remove in div, that will remove also in textarea, because it is same content, it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var idToDelete = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('img[id="'+idToDelete+'"]').remove();
})
```

```html
<button data-id="1">REMOVE IMG 1</button>
<button data-id="2">REMOVE IMG 2</button>
<button data-id="3">REMOVE IMG 3</button>
```